# What is the motivation of a separate config.hpp in boost spirit X3 program structure?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

The title itself should be quite clear, but for more context, I was going through the tutorial about [x3 program structure](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/minimal.html) in order to re-structure my own baby-parsing-project before adding a recursive AST, and it is not clear to me what level of complexity management I can achieve using the proposed layers.

Particularly, I am confused at what the `config.hpp` enables. I could find [at least one person had similar interrogations](https://www.codevamping.com/2018/12/spirit-x3-file-organization/).

The content of this file is:

```cpp
/*=============================================================================
    Copyright (c) 2001-2018 Joel de Guzman

    Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
    file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
=============================================================================*/
#if !defined(BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_MINIMAL_CONFIG_HPP)
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_MINIMAL_CONFIG_HPP

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace client { namespace parser
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    using iterator_type = std::string::const_iterator;
    using context_type = x3::phrase_parse_context<x3::ascii::space_type>::type;
}}

#endif
```

The motivations as stated in the documentation are: `Here, we declare some types for instatntaiting our X3 parser with. Rememeber that Spirit parsers can work with any ForwardIterator. We'll also need to provide the initial context type. This is the context that X3 will use to initiate a parse. For calling phrase_parse, you will need the phrase_parse_context like we do below, passing in the skipper type.`

My guess is this module is useful in complex project, but does not bring much for my simplistic application: am I wrong?

On a larger scope and for future reference, what would be is a good rule of thumb/redline not to cross in terms of modularity in the context of x3 parsers? (my lack of experience here is striking!)

Comment: There is no magic here. You use a config file if you see a great need for one - things that are needed in many places. If you don't see that need, you just don't need a common config. And nothing stops you from adding one later.

Comment: @BoP there's arguably quite a lot of magic related to X3 rule parser instantiations. But you're right, the organization into a central header is nothing magic.

Comment: @WaterFox Re.: the linked blog post (interesting find, by the way): my take on this is to never expose `phrase_parse` as a user-interface. Instead encapsulate the skipper into the grammar (where it belongs, 99.9% of the time). `x3::skip(x3::blank) [ rule_xyz << x3::eoi ]` is my go-to pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, you're asking the big, core questions!

You don't need a config.hpp.

However, if you spread *definition* of rules across translation units, you **will** need to decide on the concrete template instantiations you need to be part of your object files.

The two variable parameters here are

- iterator type
- context type

The X3 examples all assume you will have a single set for your entire grammar. The developers have decided that it would be a good way to emphasize this by putting these "global parameters" in a central header.

There are many documented cases on this site where people have run into linker errors when working from one of the spirit examples, when they switched iterator types (e.g. from `std::string::iterator` to `std::string::const_iterator`) or by introducing another skipper.

> Keep in mind you might want to facilitate multiple iterator/context combinations. Nothing prevents you from instantiating parse_rule functions for different combinations of parameters: [`BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/minimal.html#spirit_x3.tutorials.minimal.boost_spirit_instantiate).

Finally:

> **Q.** My guess is this module is useful in complex project, but does not bring much for my simplistic application: am I wrong?

You are correct. In fact, I think that X3 shines when you can encapsulate the entire grammar inside a translation unit so that you don't need to deal with explicit instantiations, or even `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE` - except for recursive rules.

Comment: It is much clearer now - thanks @sehe! Concerning the translation unit, can we imagine that if a `x3::rule` may be  templated (let's say that the ast structure it depends upon is a templated class, something like `template<class T> x3::rule<class employee, ast::employee<T>> const employee{"employee"};`), in that case everything ends up in the same translation unit anyway, right? So may it justify dumping everything related to x3 parsing  in one single hpp file?

Comment: Erm. We don't really specialize `x3::rule`. But we don't have to imagine: it is already templated, and what's more, `parse_rule` is a function template, which is precisely what leads to the requirement to explicitly instantiate for _its_ template parameter types. And yes, this is already a good argument to _just not distribute x3 grammars across TUs_, IMO. (Unrelated grammars would obviously live in separate TUs. Proper place for unit tests are subject to local dogma :))